# Summarizing Pardot activities in Salesforce by time period

Tags: pardot

I need to summarize some Pardot data in Salesforce e.g. I want a custom field that shows me per contact/prospect how many page views (or some other activity)that contact has made in the last x number of months. Is this feasible to do in Pardot and then simply sync the field across or will I have to call the Pardot api from Salesforce?

Answer (score 1):

At this time, Pardot activity data is not synced to sales cloud through objects or field data. Only through a visual force element. So with this in mind the simple answer to your question is "no".

For documentation on adding the visual force to a lead or contact page layout, follow [this](http://help.pardot.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2127330-showing-pardot-data-in-salesforce?b_id=11139#edit-your-leads-and-contacts-page-layouts-to-contain-a-new-section-for-pardot-activities-and-list-memberships) link.

Comment: if you are able to add a link from the documentation that supports this and a quote it would be very helpful, thanks!

Comment: Here you go: http://help.pardot.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2127330-showing-pardot-data-in-salesforce?b_id=11139#edit-your-leads-and-contacts-page-layouts-to-contain-a-new-section-for-pardot-activities-and-list-memberships

Comment: I dont think this is the case, at least at the time of this writing, since when enabling Pardot Engagement History within salesforce, some of this activity data is synced over to Salesforce and we are able to report on that data using Einstein Analytics. The problem we face is that we don't have access to Website visit activity, only activities related to Marketing asses such as forms, email lists, landing pages and custom redirects.

Comment: Missed the link: https://www.pardot.com/blog/how-to-report-on-marketing-activities-with-engagement-history/

Comment: Please take care to look when this was answered. It was back in 17, so is outdated